# My `find` command in script does not find files and directories with spaces in their names

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, find

Some time ago I wrote a script that moves files and directories from `Downloads` to `.Downloads` if they are older than 3 days, and delete them from this directory after 30 days. It is working just fine, but only for files with no spaces.

I investigated and found that the `find` command that I use in the script is not working as I expected for any file or directory with spaces in their name.

Here is what `find` does:

[image: find command output]

I expected to see the `find` command find the files with spaces too.

Here is the script:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash
# set -x
export DISPLAY=:0.0

# true - delete, else - move
function process(){
    if [ "$2" = "DELETE" ]; then
        rm -r "$1" && notify-send "$3 $1 deleted!"
    else
    mv "$1" "../.Downloads/$1" && notify-send "$3 $1 moved to ~/.Downloads/$1!"
    fi
}

# remove empty directories
for emptyDir in `find ~/Desktop/ ~/Downloads/ -empty -type d`; do
    notify-send "Directoy $emptyDir was deleted, because was empty!"
done
find ~/Desktop/ ~/Downloads/ -empty -type d -delete

# remove / move old files / directorie
if [ -z "$1" ] || [ "${1,,}" != "delete" ] && [ "${1,,}" != "move" ]; then
    echo "Give as parameter mode ( delete / move )"
    exit
fi

if [ "${1,,}" == "delete" ]; then
    day=30
    path=".Downloads"
    mode="DELETE"
else
    day=2
    path="Downloads"
    mode="MOVE"
  cr  
  if [ ! -d "~/.Downloads" ]; then
    mkdir -p ~/.Downloads
  fi
fi

cd ~/$path

for element in *
do
    if [ -d "$element" ]; then
        if [ $(find "$element" -type f -mtime -$day | wc -l) -eq 0 ]; then
            process "$element" "$mode" "Directory"
        fi
    else
        if [ $(find `pwd` -name "$element" -mtime +$day | wc -l) -gt 0 ]; then
            process "$element" "$mode" "File"
        fi
    fi
done
```

I would kindly ask you to tell me what I may be doing wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could put something as simple as `@reboot [username] find ~/Downloads/ -mtime +3 -exec gio trash {} \;` in your crontab. My distro is set to wipe trash files after 30 days, but that could also be done manually with the `trash-cli` package.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*tl;dr: it's not the spaces, it's the brackets*<sup>1</sup>

The `find` command's `-name` test uses shell glob expressions - adding quotes around the argument prevents glob special characters from being interpreted by your *shell*, but `find` still requires them to be escaped.

Ex.

```
$ touch 'filename with [brackets] in it'
$ find . -name 'filename with [brackets] in it'
$
```

(no results - because `[brackets]` means any single character in the set `b`, `r`, `a`, `c`, `k`, `e`, `t`, `s`); whereas

```
$ find . -name 'filename with \[brackets\] in it'
./filename with [brackets] in it
```

If you need to implement this programatically, you could perhaps use the bash shell's `printf` to add the required escapes:

```
$ element='filename with [brackets] in it'
$ find . -name "$(printf '%q' "$element")"
./filename with [brackets] in it
```

---

1. however you WILL have an issue with whitespace in the line

   ```
   for emptyDir in `find ~/Desktop/ ~/Downloads/ -empty -type d`; do
   ```

   See [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice)
2. there are a number of other issues, for example the quoted `~` in `[ ! -d "~/.Downloads" ]` will not expand to `$HOME` - generally you should avoid `~` in scripts